# Application loading images from webservice. App waits a lot in android

Tags: android, web-services, user-interface, android-asynctask

I'm developing an android app which uses web services developed in .ashx request handler.

- application waits a lot and shows the black screen while launching the aap for the first time.
- sometimes it gives error outofMemory VM budget.

Here is some code.

```
 public class Home extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        Context context = Home.this;
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ArrayList<String> BookTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> BookCoverPhotos = new ArrayList<String>();

        URL bookImageURL = null;
        Bitmap bitMapImage = null;

        View homeTabLayout;
        View reviewLayout;
        ArrayList<String> ImageUrl = new ArrayList<String>();
        ImageButton btnBack;


        // XML Parsing
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // All static variables
        static final String URL = "http://www.my_url_goes_here.com/rxxxxxxxandler.ashx";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "Book"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "BookID";
        static final String KEY_BOOKTITLE = "BookTitle";
        static final String KEY_BOOKCODE = "BookCode";
        static final String KEY_BOOKIMAGE = "BookImage";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
            // Get XML Data in a Array List

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL, "Imam Ali"); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                Node node = nl.item(i);
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                BookTitle.add(parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKTITLE));
                BookCoverPhotos.add("http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_Snaps/"+parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKCODE)+"/1.jpg");
                Log.i("URLs", BookCoverPhotos.toString());
                // String
                // imgUrl="http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_Snaps/"+parser.getValue(e,
                // KEY_BOOKCODE);
                map.put(KEY_BOOKTITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKTITLE));
                map.put(KEY_BOOKCODE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKCODE));
                map.put(KEY_BOOKIMAGE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BOOKIMAGE));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);

                Log.i("Array List", menuItems.toString());
            }

            homeTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.rel_HomeLayout);
            reviewLayout = findViewById(R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout);
            reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
            btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    homeTabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

            final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                        long arg3) {


                }
            });

       }
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Context context;
            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                context = c;
            }

            // ---returns the number of images---
            public int getCount() {

                return BookCoverPhotos.size();
            }

            // ---returns the ID of an item---
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
            // ---returns an ImageView view---
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // ImageView bmImage;
                ImageView img_BookCoverPhoto;
                img_BookCoverPhoto = new ImageView(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_style, parent, false);
                TextView txt_BooksTitle = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_BookTitle);
                txt_BooksTitle.setText(BookTitle.get(position) + "");
                img_BookCoverPhoto = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgBookCover);
                try {
                    bookImageURL = new URL(
                            BookCoverPhotos.get(position));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("URL", "ERROR");
                }

                try {
                    bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bookImageURL
                            .openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Bitmap Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("BITMAP", "ERROR");
                }

                img_BookCoverPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMapImage);

                return row;
            }
        }

    }
```

One more thing to tell you all that I'm using the XML parsing using the [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial.

- Is there any excessive unwanted code here in my app.
- Is there any way to load the first some basic UI and then app should start downloading the data (i.e images in bitmaps and text data) from the web server.
- And suggest me should i use AsyncTask, please provide some links for basic tutorials about AsyncTask.

Please provide code with some description.

Comment: Regarding out-of-memory: you need to [scale images](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) to fit into memory.

Comment: Here is another good tutorial on AsyncTask http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Asynctask` to perform network operations like fetching data from server. All the network hand shake can be done in `doInBackground()` of AsyncTask class. UI updations can be performed in `onPostExecute()`

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

[Study](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: i m sending the POST request to the server (i.e XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL, "Imam Ali"); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element )  should i put this in the AsyncTask also.